# Thread Getting Stuck At Join

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, concurrency

I'm running a thread pool that is giving a random bug.  Sometimes it works, sometimes it gets stuck at the pool.join part of this code.  I've been at this several days, yet cannot find any difference between when it works or when it gets stuck.  Please help...

Here's the code...

```
def run_thread_pool(functions_list):

    # Make the Pool of workers
    pool = ThreadPool()  # left blank to default to machine number of cores

    pool.map(run_function, functions_list)

    # close the pool and wait for the work to finish
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    return
```

Similarly, this code is also randomly getting stuck at q.join(:

```
def run_queue_block(methods_list, max_num_of_workers=20):
    from views.console_output_handler import add_to_console_queue

    '''
    Runs methods on threads.  Stores method returns in a list.  Then outputs that list
    after all methods in the list have been completed.

    :param methods_list: example ((method name, args), (method_2, args), (method_3, args)
    :param max_num_of_workers: The number of threads to use in the block.
    :return: The full list of returns from each method.
    '''

    method_returns = []

    log = StandardLogger(logger_name='run_queue_block')

    # lock to serialize console output
    lock = threading.Lock()

    def _output(item):
        # Make sure the whole print completes or threads can mix up output in one line.
        with lock:
            if item:
                add_to_console_queue(item)
            msg = threading.current_thread().name, item
            log.log_debug(msg)

        return

    # The worker thread pulls an item from the queue and processes it
    def _worker():
        log = StandardLogger(logger_name='_worker')

        while True:
            try:
                method, args = q.get()  # Extract and unpack callable and arguments

            except:
                # we've hit a nonetype object.
                break

            if method is None:
                break

            item = method(*args)  # Call callable with provided args and store result
            method_returns.append(item)
            _output(item)

            q.task_done()

    num_of_jobs = len(methods_list)

    if num_of_jobs < max_num_of_workers:
        max_num_of_workers = num_of_jobs

    # Create the queue and thread pool.
    q = Queue()

    threads = []
    # starts worker threads.
    for i in range(max_num_of_workers):
        t = threading.Thread(target=_worker)
        t.daemon = True  # thread dies when main thread (only non-daemon thread) exits.
        t.start()
        threads.append(t)

    for method in methods_list:
        q.put(method)

    # block until all tasks are done
    q.join()

    # stop workers
    for i in range(max_num_of_workers):
        q.put(None)
    for t in threads:
        t.join()

    return method_returns
```

I never know when it's going to work.  It works most the time, but most the time is not good enough.  What might possibly cause a bug like this?

Comment: When you `break` on `method is None`, is the task left on the queue => the queue will not join because it will never empty?

Comment: `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` has no `close` and `join` methods.

Comment: How would I close the threads & wait for all threads to complete then?

Comment: Why is there a `while` loop in `_worker`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call `shutdown` on the `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` object. Then `return` the result of `pool.map`.

```
def run_thread_pool(functions_list):

    # Make the Pool of workers
    pool = ThreadPool()  # left blank to default to machine number of cores

    result = pool.map(run_function, functions_list)

    # close the pool and wait for the work to finish
    pool.shutdown()
    return result
```

I've simplified your code without a `Queue` object and daemon `Thread`. Check if it fits your requirement.

```
def run_queue_block(methods_list):
    from views.console_output_handler import add_to_console_queue

    '''
    Runs methods on threads.  Stores method returns in a list.  Then outputs that list
    after all methods in the list have been completed.

    :param methods_list: example ((method name, args), (method_2, args), (method_3, args)
    :param max_num_of_workers: The number of threads to use in the block.
    :return: The full list of returns from each method.
    '''

    method_returns = []

    log = StandardLogger(logger_name='run_queue_block')

    # lock to serialize console output
    lock = threading.Lock()

    def _output(item):
        # Make sure the whole print completes or threads can mix up output in one line.
        with lock:
            if item:
                add_to_console_queue(item)
            msg = threading.current_thread().name, item
            log.log_debug(msg)

        return

    # The worker thread pulls an item from the queue and processes it
    def _worker(method, *args, **kwargs):
        log = StandardLogger(logger_name='_worker')


        item = method(*args, **kwargs)  # Call callable with provided args and store result
        with lock:
            method_returns.append(item)
        _output(item)

    threads = []
    # starts worker threads.
    for method, args in methods_list:
        t = threading.Thread(target=_worker, args=(method, args))
        t.start()
        threads.append(t)

    # stop workers
    for t in threads:
        t.join()

    return method_returns
```

Answer (score 2):

To allow your queue to join in your second example, you need to ensure that all tasks are removed from the queue.

So in your `_worker` function, mark tasks as done even if they could not be processed, otherwise the queue will never be emptied, and your program will hang.

```
def _worker():
    log = StandardLogger(logger_name='_worker')

    while True:
        try:
            method, args = q.get()  # Extract and unpack callable and arguments

        except:
            # we've hit a nonetype object.
            q.task_done()
            break

        if method is None:
            q.task_done()
            break

        item = method(*args)  # Call callable with provided args and store result
        method_returns.append(item)
        _output(item)

        q.task_done()
```